# Playing movies from the library in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, video, ipod, movie

Does anyone know whether it is possible to play a video that was synched with iTunes from within  an application of your own?
In other words - it is of course possible to programmatically create a movie player inside an application, and play movies via HTTP or movies locally stored within the home directory of the application. My question is whether it is possible to access and play a movie that was synched with iTunes, and thus resides elsewhere in the file system.

Thanks!
Ariel

Comment: As of 4.1, MPMediaLibrary only provides access to music, podcasts, and audio books in the iPod library. If enough of us file a bug asking for video access, maybe we'll get it in a future release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the MediaPlayerFramework you can only play audio synced to through itunes.

Comment: I thought they changed that in 4.0?

Comment: possibly, it has been over a year since I did anything on iOS